# Jittery mouse wheel scrolling on Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, debian, scrolling

Maybe one in ten times that I boot my computer, all mouse wheel scrolling in Firefox is very jittery. It's as if after every "down" there's a 50% chance that it will be immediately followed by an "up", so it's visually very disruptive and it's hard to make progress scrolling. The most reliable solution is to simply reboot. Does anybody know how I could fix and/or troubleshoot this effectively?

- Debian Stretch, latest KDE
- lspci: `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cypress XT [Radeon HD 5870]`
- Using open source driver: `Kernel driver in use: radeon`
- USB Logitech G3 mouse

**Update**: Also seeing flickering between two windows when I alt-tab between apps, and also sometimes a torn display where part of the previous window is drawn over the current app until it's redrawn. I guess it's more related to graphics.

Comment: At the very time when that happens, does running `journalctl -ke` (or `dmesg`) shows something weird like reports of excess IRQs happenning?

Comment: Another idea is to save the output of `cat /proc/interrupts` on a normally running system and then in the event of the misbehaving mouse, and then compare them to look whether the module which drives the USB bus to which your mouse is connected gets assigned to a different IRQ line (and may be gets to thare that line with something of interest). You can look at the output of `lsusb` to see which bus number the mouse is plugged in.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the tips. Not seeing anything too strange there, but I'm no longer convinced it's mouse-related. I'm seeing some other symptoms too so I'll update the question.